# Inductor selection for differential filtering

Tags: inductor, emi-filtering

I'm designing a line filter (230Vrms) and I am not sure how to choose the differential filtering inductors. I have calculated/simulated that I need 33µH inductors, but I am unsure how to actually select a suitable part. I do not want to build my own inductor, but choose a standard SMD part for PCB mount. What parameters of an inductor are most important for such a differential choke?
Would e.g. [MPX1D1250L330 from KEMET](https://www.mouser.dk/ProductDetail/KEMET/MPX1D1250L330?qs=P1JMDcb91o464txG3362vg%3D%3D) be suitable for such an application?

Schematic of the filter:
[image: Filter]

I have simulated the circuit in LTSpice in the following manner (DM):
[image: DM SIM]
With satisfactory results:
[image: DM SIM results]
I am simulating CM with this circuit:
[image: CM SIM]
Also with satisfactory results:
[image: CM SIM results]

Comment: Please include your calculations to get 33 uH and state/define what you are trying to filter in or out. It's not 100% clear to me what you mean by differential filtering - do you mean using two inductors; one in the forward and one in the return current path?

Comment: I have updated with a schematic. The value of 33uH is not what I am uncertain about. It is the four inductors shown in the schematic (not the CM choke). Does a special type of inductor exist that are good for filtering. For instance, inductors used for oscillators are not the ones best suited for filtering, I am told. I am interested in filtering from 9 kHz up to 30 MHz.

Comment: The two inductors on the left work together with the two capacitors on the left to make a proper differential filter. Thus, it's the combined effects of all four components that give you the effective filtering you require. You say you have calculated/simulated and concluded that 33 uH is suitable but did you do so taking into account the two capacitors I mention? I'm asking this because your question does not show any transfer function spectral responses so I'm double checking that you have done this satisfactorily.

Comment: You should also model your inductor ([this one](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/212/1/KEM_L9012_MPX-1628258.pdf)) taking into account that it has a self-resonant frequency of 5 MHz and, it will act as a capacitor above 5 MHz and may not give you the results you require. In other words, more information is needed to answer your question.

Comment: I have just updated my question with circuits and simulation results. I am satisfied with the simulation results, so my question is not so much minded towards the value of the inductor, but more which type should be used. I am aware of terminology such as "differential/normal mode choke", but looking at e.g. Mouser or Digikey, parts can't be found using these search terms. "Common mode choke" as a serach term yields thousands of results. So I need a good search term or finding out what inductor parameters are important in a filter application. Maybe the Q or another parameter, I am not certain

Comment: In your comments you said up to 30 MHz - in your diagrams it only goes to 10 MHz AND, TBH I think you need to simulate to 100 MHz. But, this is the right way forward. What is the relevance of the CM choke results to this question?

Comment: I have simulated from 10 kHz to 10 MHz because this is the  applicable MIL-STD-461 frequency range for CE102. My previous comment was wrong, I had the IEC60945 limit of 30 MHz in mind, sorry about that. The CM choke is not directly relevant, I just mention it because of the terminology. It is easy to search mouser/digikey for a CM choke, but not for a DM choke. My question is specifically about what type of inductor I should chose for L1 - L4.

Comment: OK, I'm happy with the inductor you have chosen if you are happy with the current rating it has.

Comment: I am. My best way to search for it was to search for a fixed inductor and go for a specified type such as "Power Choke" or "RF Choke".

Comment: I'd use the selection tools of somewhere like Farnell to do this - who did you use?

Comment: I used the Mouser selection tool and filtered on the "inductance value" and "type"

Comment: An equally good method. That is what EEs do.

Comment: Great, thank you very mcuh Andy!